# Pandas regex to extract everything after and before two different symbols

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe, regex-lookarounds

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11],'text':['DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject  hypo > 4 test value here','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO'],'Summary':['Test','Test1','Test2']})
```

From the above data frame, I would like to extract everything that

a) comes after `DOSE:` and before 1st hyphen `-`

b) Again extract everything that comes after 2nd hyphen `-`.

I was trying something like below

```
df['text'].str.extract('(\d+[A-Za-ZS]*(\-))',expand=True)  # doesn't work 
s1 = df['text'].str.split() # I tried using `str.split`
s1[0][1]  # it goes on like for loop which is not elegant.
```

Can help me with the above?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11],'text':['DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO'],'Summary':['Test','Test1','Test2']})
df['text'].str.replace(r'^DOSE:\s*([^-]*)-[^-]*-\s*(.*)', r'\1\2')
# 0    667 mg Inject
# 1      667 mg Tube
# 2        667 mg PO
# Name: text, dtype: object
```

The regex is

```
^DOSE:\s*([^-]*)-[^-]*-\s*(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dma0yP/1/). **Details**:

- `^DOSE:` - `DOSE:` at the start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^-]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): any 0 or more chars other than a `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[^-]*` - 0+ chars other than `-`
- `-` - a `-`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 2 (`\2` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: `r'^DOSE:\s*([^-]*)-[^-]*-\s*(.{6})', r'\1\2'`

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktor has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990061/548225) how to pick and chose substring in `text` column using `str.replace`.

Here is how to get your expected output:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11],'text':['DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO'],'Summary':['Test','Test1','Test2']})
>>> df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'\bDOSE:\s*([^-]*)-[^-]*-\s*(.*)', r'\1\2')
>>> print( df.filter(['person_id', 'text', 'Summary']) )
```

```
   person_id           text Summary
0         11  667 mg Inject    Test
1         11    667 mg Tube   Test1
2         11      667 mg PO   Test2
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/ESjLOj)

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need regex here. You can use str.split() and join 0th and 2nd item.

```
df['text_new'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: " ".join(map(x.replace("DOSE: ", "").split("-").__getitem__, [0, 2])))
```

Comment: Hi, but this results in list index out of range error when I apply on real data..

Comment: Maybe some of the values in the text column don't have 2 hyphens as expected. I had assumed that all the values will follow this format

Answer (score 1):

Lets use `str.replace`

```
df.text.str.replace(r'DOSE:\s|\s-\sTDS\swith\sfood\s-','')
```